# What strategy gives the highest DPS for a low-level Jedi Consular?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Last night I started a Jedi Consular alt and got to level 10 by the time I finished off Tython.  (I'm very familiar with it from my Knight.  I have a life, OK?  Shut up.)

What I noticed is that I was relying extremely heavily on [Double Strike](http://www.torhead.com/ability/905X72t/double-strike).  I'd just use it until I ran out of Force, and then alternate between it and [Saber Strike](http://www.torhead.com/ability/ejYE8tk/saber-strike) (which uses no Force).  Double Strike certainly does the most DPS of any move I got by level 10.

I know that Force Wave etc. is good to use with multiple enemies, but I'm more concerned with 1-on-1 encounters.  Is my strategy above the most effective for a strong enemy that I'll quickly spend all my force on?  Once my force gets low my DPS takes major hit as I alternate between the Double and Saber strikes.  Is there a more conservative approach that will keep my damage more consistent and, over time, do more total damage in the same period?

Comment: Sage or Assassin? Before level 10, what you're describing is about all you can do. Choosing an AC changes things up *dramatically* in this case -  arguably more than for any other class.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Sage. I'm planning as going into the healing tree as my primary but I'll probably keep an extra set of gear and respec as needed for damage. I am curious about this low-level stuff specifically, but I certainly wouldn't be opposed to a more in-depth answer, especially if the other low-level abilities like Project get significantly better/more useful as you level up.

Comment: Well, 1-10, you basically just fumble around and hit things. Once you choose Sage, your options open up considerably, as your force pool quadruples.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Ooh, that's good to know.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest the healing tree for leveling, as it will take longer to kill stuff, slowing down your progression.

Comment: @Amarok I've heard, yeah. Having never played a healer though I kind of want to learn on the way so I'm not hopeless in raids at 50 :P

Comment: You're going to need some time to get properly geared for the raids after reaching level 50.  I think this is a better time to learn healing on your character.

Comment: @Amarok: I would suggest using the healing tree while leveling because otherwise you end up in level 50 flashpoints without a clue how to use your abilities properly. As I've seen too often. I levelled my Sith Sorcerer that way and it went pretty fast. I suggest using a DPS companion not a tank. Ashara was great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Playing as a Sage at earlier levels, you don't have very many options to consider.  Focus on keeping enemy aggro towards your companion, keeping your companion alive, and casting damage spells when possible.

I think that Telekinetic Throw and Mind Crush (obtained at level 14) will give you the most damage overall.  Weaken Mind (obtained at level 16) is a powerful damage-over-time spell that you can tack on as well in longer fights.  Once all of those are used, you can go back to Telekinetic throw if you obtained the talent (Telekinetic Balance) that removes it's cooldown, but if not, use Disturbance.